# reverse() argument after ** must be a mapping

Tags: python, django, django-1.2

I have an inscription form that doesn't work when submitting.

I get this error:

> reverse() argument after ** must be a mapping, not str**

This is my view:

```
def inscription(request, seance_id):
    seance = get_object_or_404(Variant, id=seance_id)
    inscription_config = {'form_class': InscriptionForm,
                          'extra_context': {'seance': seance}}    

    return create_object(request, **inscription_config)
```

My form:

```
class InscriptionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Inscription
        
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        email = cleaned_data.get("mail")
        mail_confirmation = cleaned_data.get("mail_confirmation")
    
        if email != mail_confirmation:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Les deux adresses mails doivent correspondre")
    
        return cleaned_data
```

Seems what triggering the error is `inscription_config` in the return statement, but I have no idea why.

**EDIT**

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: POST Request URL:
> http://127.0.0.1:8039/formations/inscription/1/ Django Version: 1.2.5
> Python Version: 2.7.2 Installed Applications: ['django.contrib.auth',
> 'django.contrib.comments',  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
> 'django.contrib.sessions',  'django.contrib.sites',
> 'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.admin',  'ckeditor',
> 'constance',  'constance.backends.database',  'custom_flatpages',
> 'django_extensions',  'django_mobile',  'django_xmlrpc',
> 'easy_thumbnails',  'gestion_formations',  'file_uploader',  'less',
> 'mptt',  'contact',  'newsletter',  'pagination',  'south',  'sentry',
> 'sentry.client',  'indexer',  'paging',  'contentadmin',  'gallerie']
> Installed Middleware: ('annoying.middlewares.StaticServe',
> 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
> 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
> 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
> 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
> 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
> 'pagination.middleware.PaginationMiddleware')
>
> Traceback:
>
> File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
> in get_response
> 100.                     response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) File "/home/anass/projects/c139_fc_finance/fc_finance/gestion_formations/views/carts.py"
> in inscription
> 24.                          form_class= InscriptionForm  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/create_update.py"
> in create_object
> 118.             return redirect(post_save_redirect, new_object) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/create_update.py"
> in redirect
> 65.         return HttpResponseRedirect(obj.get_absolute_url()) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in
> _curried
> 55.         return _curried_func(*(args+moreargs), **dict(kwargs, **morekwargs)) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in
> get_absolute_url
> 969.     return settings.ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES.get('%s.%s' % (opts.app_label, opts.module_name), func)(self, *args, **kwargs) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/**init**.py"
> in inner
> 32.         return reverse(bits[0], None, *bits[1:3]) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py"
> in reverse
> 351.             *args, **kwargs)))
>
> Exception Type: TypeError at /formations/inscription/1/ Exception
> Value: reverse() argument after ** must be a mapping, not str

Comment: Please provide the entire traceback. The code you show here doesn't look like it will cause the error you are talking about.

Comment: This sounds a lot more like the issue is in your urls.py or something like that. Second what Ned said about full traceback.

Comment: @NedBatchelder Just added the traceback, Thanks

Comment: @Colleen here is my url : `url(r'^inscription/(?P<seance_id>\d+)/$', inscription, name='inscription'), `

Comment: Where is the code with the `form_class= InscriptionForm` line?

Comment: It's in the view ,this variable  :  `inscription_config = {'form_class': InscriptionForm,
                          'extra_context': {'seance': seance}}   `

Comment: I think we are all waiting on the entire traceback.

Comment: This appears to be a problem with your `get_absolute_url` method. You should post that.

Comment: @DanielRoseman If you can write an answer so I can accept it, and maybe explain how did you know the error came from get_absolute_url

Comment: I've got a similar issue happening - what was the problem, and how was it solved?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I try to answer, since I had the same problem but didn't find an answer online.

I think the origin of this problem is a wrong `get_absolute_url(...)` method. For example, if you write it like this:

```
@models.permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('my_named_url', kwargs={ "pk": self.pk })
```

Then it raises the exception `reverse() argument after ** must be a mapping, not str`. Fix it removing the `@models.permalink` decorator, as follows:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('my_named_url', kwargs={ "pk": self.pk })
```

or alternatively keep the decorator and modify the body, as follows:

```
@models.permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('my_named_url', (), { "pk": self.pk })
```

I think that the latter is deprecated, though.

Comment: In my code **return reverse('article-detail', kwargs=({'pk': self.post.pk}))**

Answer (score 3):

Naughty comma

```py
return redirect(reverse_lazy('team-detail', kwargs={'pk', team.pk}))
```

it should be

```py
return redirect(reverse_lazy('team-detail', kwargs={'pk': team.pk}))
```

Comment: Oops, I did it again.